# I want to append two simultaneous line with tcl, how to do that?

Tags: tcl

suppose my file contains

```
we must greap the ep
the whole ep
endpoint: /usr/home/bin/tcl_
giga/hope (v)
beginpoint" /usr/home/bin/lp50 (^)
```

I only want to print the endpoint path i.e. /usr/home/bin/tcl_giga/hope in one line.

Can anyone help me regarding the same. Actually i have write my code like :-

```
set fp [open "text" "r+"]
while {![eof $fp]} {
    gets $fp line
    puts $line
    if {[regexp {endpoint:} $line]} {
        set new_line $line
        puts $new_line
    }
}
```

But that is only printing the 1st endpoint line.

Comment: I re-formatted your question without changing any of the text. Hope I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. It allows you to change the number of lines to print after an "endpoint:" line.

```
set printNMore 0
while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} {
  if {[string first "endpoint:" $line] >= 0} {
    set printNMore 2
  }
  if {$printNMore > 0} {
    puts $line
    incr printNMore -1
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood you question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that line-at-a-time is something like this:

```
set fp [open "text" "r+"]
while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} {
    if {[string match "endpoint: *" $line]} {
        puts -nonewline [string range $line 10 end]
        # Plus the whole of the next line...
        puts [gets $fp]
    }
}
```

However, if I was doing this myself I'd slurp the whole file in at once and use a regular expression:

```
set fp [open "text" "r+"]
set contents [read $fp]
if {[regexp {endpoint: ?([^\n]+)\n([^\n]*)} -> bit1 bit2]} {
    # Print the concatenation of the capture groups
    puts "$bit1$bit2"
}
```

I could write a better pattern if I knew what the file format was more precisely…